# Tradingview Calendar Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, tradingview-api

```js
$("#loadtv").on("click",function(myfunc23){
      var chart4 = new TradingView.widget({
        container_id: 'chart4',
       "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "locale": "en",
  "importanceFilter": "-1,0,1",
  "currencyFilter": "USD"
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loadpage">
  <button id="loadtv">Show Calendar Event</button>
      <div id= "tvaa" class= "tvcx tvapp row">
         <div  id="chart4"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-events.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi,
I am trying to open the calendar widget of tradingview in a div, when a button is clicked. for some reason this same method worked with the charting widget but it isn't working for the calendar. Help appreciated!
Link to tradingview calendar widget script: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/economic-calendar/

Comment: I could put the entire tradingview script in another div container, and hide and show it when the button is clicked... Was worried that would increase page load time since its going to load the calendar script for each symbol and just hide it after.

Why i went for the javascript way for this is because if its in javascript i can have the function run for the symbol on button click, rather than page load all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another script such that you can then use the `TradingView` constructor:

```
<script src="//s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
```

The calendar widget is only one component of the ensemble. If you want to disable stuff you should check with [**this cheatsheet**](https://github.com/mmmy/css3demos/wiki/Widget-Constructor) which shows available options.

---

For some reason the WS in this SO snippet is disallowed (403).

 Therefore, you might want to check out this sample [**plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8gAToG4UraRPiOH4cXOk?p=preview).

```js
$("#loadtv").on("click", function() {
    new TradingView.widget({
        container_id: 'chart4',
        width: "100%",
        height: "1000px",
        locale: "en",
        importanceFilter: "-1,0,1",
        currencyFilter: "USD",
        symbol: "NASDAQ:AAPL",
        interval: "D",
        timezone: "America/New_York",
        theme: "White",
        style: 1,
        toolbar_bg: "rgba(0, 0, 196, 1)",
        withdateranges: true,
        hide_side_toolbar: false,
        allow_symbol_change: true,
        details: false,
        hotlist: false,
        calendar: true,
        news: [],
        hideideas: true,
        show_popup_button: true,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<button id="loadtv">Show Calendar Event</button>
<div id="chart4"></div>
```

Comment: How to remove this loader or change its color?